# zf2 form binding after isValid

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I just moved from zf1 to zf2 and some simple task are giving me a headache.
I have some filters on my form. Filters are being run on form isValid function andafter this function been run, I expected filtered data to be rebind to the form.

I an using zend framework 2.2.7

This is my controller code:

```
<?php

namespace Test\Controller;

use Test\Entity\Product;
use Test\Form\CreateProduct;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class TestController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
      $form = new CreateProduct();
         $product = new Product();
         $form->bind($product);

         $request = $this->getRequest();
         if ($request->isPost()) {
             $form->setData($request->getPost());

             if ($form->isValid()) {
                 var_dump($product);
             }
             $form->bind($product); // manual rebind seems to work but look hackish 

         }

         return array(
             'form' => $form,
         );
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand your need for applying filters even when the data is not valid. But anyways when you will submit again, its going to go through the `isValid()` method call and apply the filters. So at the end, you do get filtered data.

Comment: Yeah my model have filtered data but values which are on the form are still data which been posted without filter being apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you like to "rebind" the data back to the form (after the validation fail) use `$form->populateValues()`

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
if( $request->isPost() )
{
    if( $form->isValid() )
    {
        $validatedFormData = $form->getData();
        // do something

    } else {

        // populate posted values to form
        $form->populateValues($request->getPost());

        // fetch form errors $form->getMessages()
        // whatever
    }
}
```